# OverflowError when trying to convert generators to lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, date, generator

I'm trying to extract dates from txt files using datefinder.find_dates which returns a generator object. Everything works fine until I try to convert the generator to list, when i get the following error.

I have been looking around for a solution but I can't figure out a solution to this, not sure I really understand the problem neither.

```
import datefinder 
import glob

path = "some_path/*.txt"
files = glob.glob(path)  

dates_dict = {} 

for name in files:
   with open(name, encoding='utf8') as f:
       dates_dict[name] = list(datefinder.find_dates(f.read()))
```

Returns :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-a4b508b01fe8> in <module>()
  1 for name in files:
  2     with open(name, encoding='utf8') as f:
----> 3         dates_dict[name] = list(datefinder.find_dates(f.read()))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datefinder\__init__.py in 
find_dates(self, text, source, index, strict)
 29         ):
 30 
---> 31             as_dt = self.parse_date_string(date_string, captures)
     32             if as_dt is None:
     33                 ## Dateutil couldn't make heads or tails of it

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datefinder\__init__.py in 
parse_date_string(self, date_string, captures)
     99         # otherwise self._find_and_replace method might corrupt 
them
    100         try:
--> 101             as_dt = parser.parse(date_string, default=self.base_date)
    102         except ValueError:
    103             # replace tokens that are problematic for dateutil

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py in 
parse(timestr, parserinfo, **kwargs)
   1354         return parser(parserinfo).parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1355     else:
-> 1356         return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
   1357 
   1358 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py in 
parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
    651             raise ValueError("String does not contain a date:", 
timestr)
    652 
--> 653         ret = self._build_naive(res, default)
    654 
    655         if not ignoretz:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py in 
_build_naive(self, res, default)
   1222             cday = default.day if res.day is None else res.day
   1223 
-> 1224             if cday > monthrange(cyear, cmonth)[1]:
   1225                 repl['day'] = monthrange(cyear, cmonth)[1]
   1226 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\calendar.py in monthrange(year, month)
    122     if not 1 <= month <= 12:
    123         raise IllegalMonthError(month)
--> 124     day1 = weekday(year, month, 1)
    125     ndays = mdays[month] + (month == February and isleap(year))
    126     return day1, ndays

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\calendar.py in weekday(year, month, day)
    114     """Return weekday (0-6 ~ Mon-Sun) for year (1970-...), month(1- 12),
    115        day (1-31)."""
--> 116     return datetime.date(year, month, day).weekday()
    117 
    118 

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Can someone explain this clearly?

Thanks in advance

REEDIT : After taking into consideration the remarks that were made, I found a minimal, readable and verifiable example. The error occurs on :

```
import datefinder

generator = datefinder.find_dates("466990103060049")

for s in generator:
   pass
```

Comment: Your code is not self-contained, since you do not show the contents of your file that causes the problem. Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see the problem ourselves. Cutting the problem down to one small file may enable you to see the problem.

Comment: Some of your seems to be invalid, you should print the the entries before parsing so you can detect which are the invalid ones.

Comment: (After the edit) What does "fiffuse" mean--is that a typographical error? Show us one of those files and we may be able to find the problem in the file. You could cut the file in half and see which half causes the problem, and do that repeatedly until you get down to one paragraph or line. There could be a weird error in your file or a bug in `datefinder.find_dates` but you do not give enough information for us to tell.

Comment: If you can't show us the files, start tearing stuff out until you get the minimum example that still exhibits the error. *That* should be something you can show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a bug in the library you are using. It is trying to parse the string as a year, but that this year is too big to be handled by Python. The library that `datefinder` is using says that it raises an `OverflowError` in this instance, but that `datefinder` is ignoring this possibility.

One quick and dirty hack just to get it working would be to do:

```
>>> datefinder.ValueError = ValueError, OverflowError
>>> list(datefinder.find_dates("2019/02/01 is a date and 466990103060049 is not"))
[datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 1, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well. Could you give a bit more information on what you did exactly by setting datefinder.ValueError = ValueError, OverflowError?

Comment: You can pass a tuple of exceptions to the except clause of a try/except. This catches all instances of any if those exceptions. I'm hijacking the module's reference to ValueError and redefining it as the tuple `ValueError, OverflowError`. So the problematic except clause now catches both exceptions. It's far from ideal, and I suggest you do `del datefinder.ValueError` afterwards to undo the changes.